# LM317T Resistor Values

Tags: lm317

I am trying to prototype this circuit:

[image: PSBench.gif]

However I do not have a 2K Ohm potentiometer for R2, the closest I have is a 100K. So I have used 100K for R2 and 10K for R1. Using the forumula at the bottom these should be valid values for the resistors, however my output voltage only range between 0.01V and 0.4V. Also the output voltage slowly creeps by 0.01V increments the longer I keep the circuit switched on.

I have checked the wiring many, many times and replaced the LM317T twice and checked every component individually but always get the same problem. Can someone tell me what is wrong please?

I rebuilt the circuit so  it is easier to understand the connections:

[image: breadboard1]
[image: breadboard2]

Comment: please add a photograph of the assembled circuit.

Comment: I'm not sure a photograph would be helpful because of how close all the components are on the breadboard (it would be difficult to make out all the connections). I am sure the wiring is correct, I have checked it 20 times atleast...

Comment: What are the voltages on pins 1 and 3?

Comment: pin 1 = 0.052V and pin 3 = 0.752V, both dropping steadily by 0.01V roughly each second.

Comment: look upstream if there is only 0.75 V input to the circuit.  What transformer are you using?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the recommended value for R1 is 240 ohms - you can probably go up to 1K or so, but 10K is much too far from the recommended value to expect proper operation.

Comment: There will be some error from 10k resistance, but the circuit should still function as a regulator.  Use the long equation in the circuit diagram above.

Comment: If you are only getting 0.75 volts at the input to the LM317, there must be something seriously wrong _before_ the 317 - check that the diodes are inserted with the correct plolarity, and that the transformer is really producing 18VAC, and is connected to the diodes.  You should have about 25V across the 3300uF capacitor.  Are the voltages you reported measured with respect to the "common" terminal of the circuit?

Comment: The transformer is marked as having a 12V 2A output, the actual output is 15.87 VAC (unloaded). The diode bridge rectifier works because it gives roughly 14.8V DC when unloaded. When I connect only a 3300uF 25V capacitor to the bridge rectifier the output drops to 0.4V, i don't know if this is to be expected?

Comment: @Adamme - you must have a poor connection somewhere - when you add the 3300 uF capacitor, the DC voltage should rise to about 21 volts.  Do you have the 3300 uF capacitor conneted with the correct polarity?

Comment: Are you measuring the bridge rectifier output on "AC volts" or "DC volts" on your multimeter?

Comment: Definitely using the the DC setting to measure the bridge rectifier output, both when the 3300uF capacitor is connected and not connected. I'm waiting on a delivery of 2k pots as my next troubleshooting step (see Barry's answer below). @Peter Bennett: The polarity of the capacitor is correctly aligned (the same as in the photograph).

Comment: @Adamme are you absolutely certain that the meter was set to DC Volts when measuring the bridge output with and without the 3300 uF capacitor?  If the meter was set to AC, it would indicate a large ripple voltage without the capacitor, then a very small ripple vlotage when you add the capacitor.  To check that your meter is set to DC volts and working correctly, measure the voltage of a 9 volt (or any) battery - if the meter reads near zero, either it is broken, or there is some problem with your measurement technique.

Comment: @Adamme  There is no point worrying about resistor values until you can reliably measure the expected DC voltage at the input to the LM317.

Comment: @PeterBennett You are right, I have tried building the bridge rectifier on a separate board, where the output is measuring 14.15 Volts DC (meter defintely set to DC), as soon as I connect the 3300uF capacitor, the output voltage drops to 0.5V DC. I have tested the meter on 1.5V alkaline battery, which gives me a 1.6V reading so the meter is working. I am however using a laminated core transformer with wiring as shown in this diagram: http://www.decdun.me.uk/gc/trafo%20wiring.jpg . Do I need to ground the middle two output terminals (mine are not connected to anything)?

Comment: This is how I wired the transformer http://imgur.com/jO0C1bk . The top 2 terminals are mains AC and the bottom two are connected to the bridge rectifier input. I'm not sure if thed the two middle bottom  terminals be connected together and earthed.

Comment: @Adamme your link for the transformer wiring diagram takes me to a website hosting site - no transformer details there.  However, looking at the photo of the transformer, I suspect that it has two separate 12 volt secondary windings - if so, those two unconnected terminals on the bottom could be connected together to give 24 VAC, or (better) you could move the the right wire to the second terminal from the left - but before doing that, measure the AC voltage on each pair of terminals to see what is really connected to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformer was incorrectly wired, causing a severe voltage drop when a load was applied to it. (See Peter Bennet's comment under the question for more details.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information in your schematic the voltage across the 3300 uf capacitor should be about 25 VDC which is the peak voltage of the 18 VAC at the secondary of the transformer.  Since you are only getting 0.752V, something is clearly amiss.  Try disconnecting pin 3 of the LM317T and then measuring the voltage across the 3300 uf capacitor.  If it is about 25 VDC, then something is wrong with either your wiring or the LM317T.  If it is not, then you have a problem with either the transformer, rectifier, or capacitor.  In any case, I believe that your choice of values for R1 and R2 will not work in this circuit. The LM317T contains a 1.25V reference that appears across pins 1 and 2.  The voltage divider formed by R1 and R2 causes the LM317T to change its output voltage to keep the 1.25V across R1.  That is the basis of the first term of the equation for the output voltage.  The problem is the second term. The LM317T outputs a small current from pin 1, designated as IADJ, which is nominally about 50 microamperes.  This current flows through R2 and increases the output voltage by IADJ X R2 which accounts for the second term in the equation. When the recommended value of 2K is used for R2, this second term  becomes 50 microamperes X 2K or 0.1V which is small compared to the usual output voltage of the LM317T.  Also, the LM317T is designed to keep IADJ constant with temperature so as to not affect the stability of the output.  However, you are using 100K for R2, so that IADJ now causes the output voltage to increase by 50 microamperes X 100K or 5 volts.  This is a large fraction of the expected output voltage and could go as high as 10 volts since the specified maximum for IADJ is 100 microamperes. The data sheet is not clear on this point but I believe the designers expect the current through R1 to be much greater than IADJ.  With the recommended value of 220 ohms, the current through R1 is 1.25V/220 or 5.68 milliamperes which is 57 times higher than IADJ.  With R1 equal to 10k, the current drops to 0.125 milliamperes or 125 microamperes which is only 1.25 times the maximum value of IADJ.  I strongly suggest that you find a pot much closer to 2k, lower the value of R1 accordingly, and try the circuit again.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I had no idea I ADJ was important and went off the guess that keeping the ratio R1/R2 would be sufficient. Went to town to buy some 2k pots but couldn't find any so I ordered some online, I will be back to let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

The size of R2 can skew the regulation point. The adjust pin actually sources 100 microamps of current, which combines with the current from R1 to set the R2 voltage and the ultimate set point for the regulator.

[image]

Beyond that, the circuit appears reasonable to me (from a schematic point of view). You should check the steady (DC) voltage at the 3300 microfarad cap and at the 10 microfarad cap on the adjust pin.